# Hide/show part of the window with a button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple form containing a main view and also some text boxes and an "add" button that I use for adding data that is displayed in the main view (and stored in a text file). What I want to do is to add a little button that will toggle hiding/showing of the adding controls. Such button usually is a small square containing two arrowheads pointing up/down depending on the state. How do I do that?

(I'm sorry for the terrible title, but I don't know the proper name for this. Could anyone tell me?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's something built-in in WinForms for that. When I needed to do something similar, I just changed the Height of the form...

Answer (score 2):

```
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(required_width, required_height);
```

use a `bool` for hiding/showing

Answer (score 1):

You can use the forms `Height` property and the controls could be hidden with `Control.Visible = false`

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is "Collapsible panel".

A quick google/codeproject search will provide you with some links:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/TgXPPanel.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/XPCollapsGroupBox.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CollapsibleGroupBox.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a SplitContainer control and play with the Panel2.Collapsed property by sitting it to true or false

put the control that you want to hide/show inside panel2 and put the button in panel1. Change the Orientation property to Vertical, and there you go