# Swing method to show or hide part of a panel on button click?

Tags: java, swing, components

I'd like to be able to show and hide (and therefore grow and shrink the jpanel as appropriate) in my swing application. I've seen something similar on websites that I imagine uses JS and JQuery.

What I'm after is the ability to click a button (that might say 'Advanced options') that then 'slowly' grows the panel and reveals (`setVisible(true)`) components.

Is this possible using Swing? I've tried looking round the web, and SO but I only seem to get JQuery questions, or unhelpful Java posts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793674/hide-show-part-of-the-window-with-a-button-click) is the closest I've found.

Comment: use a thread to  slowly hide component

Comment: @user3313050: no, that would be unnecessarily complicated as you'd have to be sure that all Swing code is called on the EDT. Simplest is to use a Swing Timer for your animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Swing Timer to animate your slide. For example, this link has code that places the components in a JLayeredPane and slides one component over the other, again using a Swing Timer:  [slide effect with JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11283582/522444).

Another useful effect is to fade out from one JPanel to another. For an example of this that uses a Swing Timer as well as a CardLayout, please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275584/522444).